# Using std::wstring_view to define const std::wstring keys for a map

Tags: c++, macros, c++17, stdmap, widestring

I'm trying to setup a structure using a `std::map` with `std::wstring` as a key and attempting to use some syntactic surgar to make key declaration/definition easy via macros and `std::wstring_view` (for const definition of key). Is there a way to use `std::wstring_view` value as `std::wstring` map key?

My map is defined as follows...

```
class Parameter
{
public:
    typedef std::wstring Key; 

    std::variant<void*, int, bool, float, std::wstring> value_;

    ...
}

typedef std::map<Parameter::Key, Parameter> Parameters;
```

I can access the map no problem using string literals...

```
myParameters[L"SomeKey"] = L"SomeValue";
```

However if using a `std::wstring_view` to define a const key, gives me an error when trying to use it as a key.

```
static constexpr std::wstring_view SomeKeyDefined = L"SomeKey";
myParameters[SomeKeyDefined] = L"SomeValue";
```

Results in...

```
C2679: binary '[': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const std::wstring_view' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

It's my understanding that `std::wstring_view` is simply a wrapper to allow me to define a const `std::wstring`. Is it possible to use `std::wstring_view` value as a map key?

Ultimately I would like to be able to have some syntactic sugar (via macros) to aid in defining some const keys. e.g.

```
#define PARAMETER_KEY_STRING(x) L # x
#define PARAMETER_KEY(name) static constexpr std::wstring_view name = PARAMETER_KEY_STRING(name);
```

Which would allow me to define const `std::wstring` map keys as follows

```
PARAMETER_KEY(SomeKey)
```

If this cannot be done, is there a another way to have some syntactic sugar for defining `std::wstring` const keys for a map?

Comment: There is no implicit conversion from `std::wstring_view` to `std::wstring`. And `std::map::operator[]` requires argument which type is `key` (here it is `std::wstring`). So you have to make explicit conversion.

Comment: You can always define a transparent comparator and have anything vaguely string-like being usable as a search key.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI transparent comparator is interesting proposal, but do not work with `operator[]`: https://godbolt.org/z/aYcGeEq5a

Comment: @MarekR right, this should be available in C++26 only.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is `std::map::operator[]` which accepts only `key` type - in your case `std::wstring` and the fact there is no implicit conversion  from `std::wstring_view` to `std::wstring`.

There are two ways to fix it:

```cpp
myParameters[std::wstring{SomeKeyDefined}] = L"SomeValue";
```

Or IMO better:

```cpp
myParameters.emplace(SomeKeyDefined, L"SomeValue");
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/aYcGeEq5a

Answer (score 1):

The constructor in `std::wstring` converting from `std::wstring_view` (or rather *StringViewLike*) is `explicit` so you either need to construct a `std::wstring` explicitly (`std::wstring(my_string_view)`) **or** you could use a transparent comparator and put your map in a wrapper class where you provide an `operator[]` that can be used with `std::wstring_view`s without having to create a `std::wstring` every time you do a lookup in the map.

The comparator needs to have some definition of `is_transparent` and a set of  `operator()` overloads to do comparison between the different types you'd like to be able to compare. In this case, only one overload is needed because a `std::wstring_view` can be implicitly constructed from a `std::wstring`, so the comparator becomes rather simple:

```cpp
struct comp {
    using is_transparent = void;

    bool operator()(std::wstring_view lhs, std::wstring_view rhs) const {
        return lhs < rhs;
    }
};
```

You'd then fill the wrapper with the member functions you need. Example:

```cpp
template<class T>
class wstring_map {
    struct comp { /* defined as above */ };

    std::map<std::wstring, T, comp> m_map;
public:
    using value_type = typename decltype(m_map)::value_type;

    wstring_map(std::initializer_list<value_type> il) : m_map(il) {}
    
    // your custom operator[]
    T& operator[](std::wstring_view sv) {        
        if (auto it = m_map.find(sv); it != m_map.end()) return it->second;
        // the key doesn't exist, insert it:
        return m_map.emplace(std::wstring(sv), T{}).first->second;
    }
};
```

If the `find` succeeds, no `std::wstring` needs to be created and a reference to the existing *Value* will be returned, otherwise a `std::wstring` *Key* must be created and inserted in the map to default construct `T`.

Usage:

```
int main() {
    wstring_map<std::wstring> map1{
        {L"keyone", L"valueone"},
        {L"keytwo", L"valuetwo"},
    };

    std::wstring_view key1 = L"keyone";
    std::wcout << map1[key1] << '\n'; // valueone
    
    wstring_map<int> map2{
        {L"keyone", 1},
    };
    std::wstring_view key2 = L"keytwo";
    std::wcout << map2[key2] << '\n'; // 0 because keytwo didn't exist before
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/M13K7ex3n)